# When using typeid on a polymorphic object, must it be defined?

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++, typeid

When using `typeid` on a polymorphic object, I think the object must be defined (not just a declaration) because `typeid` operation needs to get the object's information at **runtime**. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class D {
    virtual ~D() {}
};
extern D d;

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(d).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(d) << std::endl;
}
```

And with [clang 3.4](http://rextester.com/JPLNWO25452), I got the link error:

> undefined reference to `d'

But with [g++ 4.8.1](http://rextester.com/ZXLKL54821), it works well and I got the result:

> 1D
>   8

My question:

1. Which one is right?
2. How does g++ implement `typeid`? How can it get the information from a polymorphic object without definition?

Comment: I don't know which one is correct, but [g++ got linker error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/288ddd8f4e70f535) with `extern D &d`. So maybe g++ is smart enough to figure out that `d` must be type of `D` (given it is not pointer nor reference)

Comment: @BryanChen But maybe no allowed by the standard...?

Comment: I think the reason why g++ seems to work well is the type of `d`. It's *statically* `D`, so compiler knows the type of `d`, and maybe g++ optimized-out the code to get `typeinfo` of `d` in runtime. However, if the type of `d` is `D &` or `D *`, compiler does not know its type **in compile-time**, so it cannot optimized-out the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

> a) If expression is a glvalue expression that identifies an object of a polymorphic type (that is, a class that declares or inherits at least one virtual function), the `typeid` expression evaluates the expression and then refers to the `std::type_info` object that represents the dynamic type of the expression. If the result of the evaluated expression is a null pointer, an exception of type `std::bad_typeid` or a type derived from `std::bad_typeid` is thrown.

Sounds like clang 3.4 is right.

**Update**

The standard says:

> When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a polymorphic class type (10.3), the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type of the most derived object (1.8) (that is, the dynamic type) to which the glvalue refers. If the glvalue expression is obtained by applying the unary * operator to a pointer and the pointer is a null pointer value (4.10), the typeid expression throws the `std::bad_typeid`
>   exception (18.7.3).

It is slightly different from the language used by cppreference.com but it still points to clang 3.4 being right.

Comment: The wording "evaluates the expression" doesn't actually appear in the standard.

Comment: @Brian, if the expression evaluates to a polymorphic type, I don't understand how it is possible for the compiler to deduce the type information at compile time, which g++ is able to some how pull off.

Comment: @RSahu: It's easy enough, `d` is not a reference, thus the most derived type of `d` is `D`. Just because it's possible does not mean it's right though...